# How do I get an item from an ArrayList in another class and reference it in an ArrayList in my current class (using only indexes)?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let me preface this by saying that I'm new to programming and have only been learning Java and OOP for around six weeks (so please excuse me if I use incorrect terminology). I will attempt to explain my issue methodically:

I am creating a grid for a small application I am making. For various reasons, it is important that I can reference cells, or 'co-ordinates' on the grid but I can also find out (and perhaps manipulate) what is in an individual row or column.

The Grid class has a constructor which fills two ArrayLists ('horizontals' and 'verticals') with new HLine and VLine objects (horizontal and vertical lines), respectively.

The HLine class has a constructor which fills its own Arraylist with new unnamed Cell objects. Fine so far.

I then want the VLine's constructor to fill ArrayList with references to the correct corresponding cells that already exist in my just-created HLine objects, purely by referencing their indices (so the Cell in the first HLine's 0 position is the *same instance* of Cell referenced in the first VLine's 0 position).

I'm pretty sure I worked out how to find the right cell, but I'm having trouble telling Java which cell I want (using only ArrayList indices, and not names).

Here's what I have for this section:

```
public VLine(int chosensize){

    //get the right cells for the VLines

    //loop through columns and iterate thisCol

    for(int i=0;i<chosensize;i++){

        int thisCol = i;


        //loop through HLines getting the cell at number 'thisCol' from each one
        //i.e. HLine1 column0, HLine2 column0, HLine3 column0


        for(int x=0;x<chosensize;x++){

            //this is not my code attempt, but should show what I want to do (but can't get it to compile): 

            HLine thisHLine = myGrid.horizontals.get(x);

            this.myCells.add(thisHLine.get(thisCol));

        }

    }
```

I'm not sure if it's something silly, like I have to send the array object as an argument into my constructor, but I thought I'd be able to reference it through the myGrid object.

I also thought about making a getter for cells in my HLine, but isn't the ArrayList's 'get' pretty much performing that function?

It may, of course, be that I've missed a fundamental rule of some kind - either way, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use a multidimensional array, and store only one reference to each cell? In other words, why do you want to have constructs for both horizontal and vertical lines within the grid, which are redundant for many use cases?

Comment: I think you're right. I'm still going to use line objects, but they will purely be used for indexing an existing 2d 'master' array. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using one two-dimensional array(if you know that your grid is going to have constant number of rows and col) or two arraylists inside the grid class, so that you could access the same way this array/arraylist from other places, such as your two Line classes. I'd also recommend making this array private and providing getter and setter methods of the Grid class with 1 parameter to access and read/write the specific index that you are interested from the arrays.

Does that make sense? I could elaborate on it a bit.

Comment: It's interesting you say that - that's kind of how I started before deciding to go down the route of completely controlling my grid through line objects. I have a few different Grid sizes, but I could control that through Grid subclasses with constructors. I was going to create line objects that looped through the 2d grid array just for the purpose of keeping an index of each row/column. A developer at work advised this method. Thinking about it, using my original single 2d array in a myGrid is a great way to have an absolute reference to my unnamed Cell objects at all times, using a getter.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more this seems like the obvious fix. This was where my original approach was headed, but a developer at my workplace recommended just using the line objects. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Please note - I'm not a professional developer. My suggestion is based solely on experience with dealing with similar problems. There may be better solutions than this one.